# Angular Select List [selected] directive not working?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I want to select the Region and city as the value of the dropdown when I tried to edit.
here is the code:

```
<select class="form-select inputBoxRadius" id="addressRegion" style="width: 228px; height: 55px;" 
                          formControlName="Region" (change)="onRegionChange($event)">
                            <!-- Add your options for regions here -->
                            <option *ngFor="let item of regionList" [value]="item.Text" [selected]="item.Selected">{{ item.Value }}</option>
                          </select>
```

here is the data from api call.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYcca.png)

I expecting to display the selected with value of true.